# .htacces: RewriteMatch all traffic EXCEPT for two URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the below method to redirect users on my site from the root directory to a subdirectory as followed:

```
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## Forcing https

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]

############################################
## Capturing all traffic and redirecting it to necessary subdirectory

RedirectMatch ^/$ /subdirectory/
```

This works well and I can still get to one of my exceptions which is ***/admin*** (Full URL: /index.php/admin) no problem. I didn't have to specify any exception - it just worked.

Now I am trying to access my API URL and it manages to redirect it to /subdirectory instead of allowing it. The URL: ***http://website.com/index.php/api/action***

I see there is a way of excluding directories with the ***RewriteRule*** method but does this apply for the ***RedirectMatch*** method as well?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^uploads($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Using Magento. The admin URL uses "pretty URLs" to hide /index.php/admin and the API I'm using requires /index.php as well. I'm not certain how far-reaching taking that course of action would be so I'm trying to stick with something more manageable such as .htaccess.

Comment: Yes, it's technically an extension of Magento that piggy-backs on core Magento. In order to work it must fire up Magneto's index.php file as you would do to access any other section of the site.

Comment: What is the reason of using `RedirectMatch` instead of `RewriteRule` here?

Comment: @anubhava Great question. I found another example on Stack Overflow that utilized it to achieve the same result. I'm always open to changing it if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to stick with `mod_rewrite` instead of using `mod_alias` based rules here:

```
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## Forcing https

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]

############################################
## Capturing all traffic and redirecting it to necessary subdirectory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(index\.php/)?(api|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /subdirectory/ [L,R]
```

Comment: So the RewriteRule works for root traffic but what about excluding this URL: http://website.com/index.php/api/action If I attempt to access it I get redirected to s/ubdirectory. Can I implement this?:      RewriteRule !^index.php/api/action($|/) ^/?$ /subdirectory/ [L,R]

Comment: Hmmmmmm, the change didn't allow the URL. I found out however that I can drop index.php and just use /api/action if that helps.

Comment: Do you want to skip `/api/action` for `http->https` rule also?

Comment: It appears I had a conflicting rule. This led me to the answer. Thank you!